# Google on my iOS devices is stuck in a different region than I live in

Tags: ios, wifi, network, geolocation, search-engine

For some reason, my browser always defaults to New Zealand. I've reset my location in the Store and in the settings, but it always pulls up google.co.nz when doing a search and the default map centers on New Zealand when I turn off my location.

Anyone know how I can set the region of the browser to match where I am?

Comment: Does this happen over 3G or WiFi or both? If it's only WiFi, is it possible that your network is configured to use a proxy?

Comment: It's WiFi. My iPad is WiFi only. And i'm not using a proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

In Settings>General>International for some reason New Zealand was selected instead of United States. I had to close out safari, clear 
browsing data and then re-search something from the iPad search bar and it finally worked.